Getting exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker:(406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1') when channel.start_consuming is called in version 3.8
When consumer is started, I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 38, in <module>
consume()
File "app.py", line 21, in consume
channel.start_consuming()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1883, in start_consuming
self._process_data_events(time_limit=None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2049, in _process_data_events
raise self._closing_reason  # pylint: disable=E0702
pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1')

import pika
import json

def consume():
    print('Connecting to server ...')
    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host="rabbitmq"))
    except pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError as exc:
        print("Failed to connect to RabbitMQ service. Message won't be processed.")
        return

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='queue_1', durable=True)

    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(queue='queue_1',
                          on_message_clalback=callback, auto_ack=True)
    print('Waiting for messages...')
    try:
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Notify Kiotapay of error in sending messages
        channel.stop_consuming()
    connection.close()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    message_data = json.loads(body)
    print("Received message:", message_data)

    # Add your message processing logic here
    # send_email(message_data)

    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    consume()

I tried adding no_ack=False to channel.basic_consume() as suggested in some related questions, I was the getting TypeError: basic_consume() got an unexpected keyword argument "no_ack"`.
